# Convert auto generated html to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using some javascript/jquery in an asp.net mvc view and I'm appending some html code using a html helper.

```
$("#update").append('@Html.CustomHelper(m => m.Values)');
```

The custom html helper generates a block of html a few lines long. The problem is the first line starts with a `'` and then the last line ends with a `'`, but the rest of the lines aren't string.

Is there a way in **JavaScript or jQuery** to `stringify` the block of **HTML**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach would be to encode the string for Javascript on the ASP.NET side.
Use maybe:

```
HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(string)
```

This way you are guaranteed to have a consistent and valid encoding without worrying about quotes etc.. Just substitute your string in the method.

Comment: Nice one, I created a RawCustomHelper that calls CustomHelper and returns the now javascript encoded html.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your `CustomHelper` method return a properly JS-Encoded encoded string. Right before you return from your method call, you could use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(yourStringHere)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Html.Raw`

```
$("#update").append("@Html.Raw(Html.CustomHelper(m => m.Values))");
```

Comment: Good solution but I thought creating a RawCustomHelper felt a bit neater.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use double quotes?

```
$("#update").append("@Html.CustomHelper(m => m.Values)");
```

Comment: Double quotes or apostrophes isn't the issue here although I did not mean to use both in my example.